# Program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input

Tags: c

I am supposed to write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. When I compile my current code I get some random output... Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Ok guys… I tried to take into account your suggestions, so here is what I came up with so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OUT 0
#define IN 1

int main()

{

int c, i, j, state, word, wlen;
word = wlen = 0;
state = OUT;
int length [20];

  for (i=0; i<20; ++i) {
  length[i] = 0;            // initialize elements
  i = 0;
  }

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF  && word < 20) {

      if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')

      {  

       state = OUT;

      }


      else if (state == OUT)

      {
        ++word;
        state == IN;

      }

     else if (word == OUT)

     {
         state = IN;
         ++word;
         ++length[wlen];
     }


       else if (state == IN)

      {
        ++length[wlen];

      }



   }   

   printf( "histogram:");
  for (i=0; i<20; ++i)     {
 printf( "%2d", i);
 for (j = 0; j < length[i]; ++j)
    printf("*");
    printf("\n");

   }
}
```

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: 0) `i<length[i];` is wrong.

Comment: 1) `c!= ' ' || c!= '\n' || c!= '\t'` is wrong.

Comment: You never reset `length` from `100` after the first loop.  You should probably identify the length of a word before changing anything in the `length` array.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'or' comparisons should be 'and' comparisons, and your print statements at the end print chars instead of ints — you should use %d not %c. Also, your for loop needs braces if you want that print statement for a newline character to run more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm appears to be workable. Your implementation has at least the following problems:

1) The loop at the beginning does nothing sensible:

`for (i=0; i<length[i]; ++i)
       length[i] = 0;            // initialize elements`

You probably meant to do

`for (i=0; i<sizeof(length); ++i)
       length[i] = 0;            // initialize elements`

2) The next section is very confusing. I think you are trying to start i at 0 at the beginning of a word (non-whitespace), increment length[i] when you see a non-whitespace character, then on the next character decrement length[i-1] and increment length[i].

A better idea might be to have a variable with some meaningful name like `current_word_length`, set it to 0 at the start, increment it when you see non-whitespace, and when you see white-space, increment `length[current_word_length]` and then set `current_word_length` to 0.

3) the loop at the end which is supposed to print the values has the same bug as #1,

4) you are trying to print the number of occurrences of the character (a count) as if it were a character.

Assuming you don't want a true histogram, just a table, try:

`for (i=0; i<sizeof(length); ++i)
        printf("%d %d", i, length[i]);
    printf("\n");`

5) If you really want a histogram, something like:

`for (i=0; i<sizeof(length); ++i) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        for (j = 0; j<length[i]; j++) {
             printf("x");
        }
        printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");`

Comment: @Carl Norum - yep, should be sizeof(length)/sizeof(length(0))

Comment: or #define HISTOGRAM_SIZE 100, and use that throughout.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void count(FILE *fp, int size, int lens[size]);
void display(FILE *fp, int size, const int lens[size]);

int main(void){
    const int max_word_length = 100;
    int length[max_word_length];
    memset(length, 0, sizeof(length));//0 initialize

    count(stdin, max_word_length, length);
    display(stdout, max_word_length, length);

    return 0;
}

void count(FILE *fp, int size, int lens[size]){
    int ch, word_len = 0;

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(isspace(ch)){//state = OUT;
            if(word_len){
                if(word_len >= size){
                    ++lens[0];
                } else {
                    ++lens[word_len];
                }
                word_len = 0;
            }
        } else {//state = IN;
            ++word_len;
        }
    }
}

void disp_aux(FILE *fp, int mark, int num){
    for(int i = 1; i <= num; ++i){
        fputc(i % 10 == 0 ? '0' : mark, fp);
    }
    fputc('\n', fp);
}

void display(FILE *fp, int size, const int lens[size]){
    int mark = '*';
    fprintf(fp, "histogram :\n");
    int w = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", size);
    for(int i = 1; i < size; ++i){
        if(lens[i]){
            fprintf(fp, "%*d : ", w, i);
            disp_aux(fp, mark, lens[i]);
        }
    }
    if(lens[0]){
        fprintf(fp, "%d+: ", size);
        disp_aux(fp, mark, lens[0]);
    }
}
```