# read in input, then read in each char in c programming

Tags: c, eof, c-strings

I am working on a practice problem from my textbook by kernigan and ritchie (again for practice, not for credit).

The problem states to write a program that prints a histogram of the lengths of words in its input.

I want to do this by printing a "_" for every char that I read. However, I'm having a lot of trouble reading chars.

Right now, my program looks like this:

```
int main(){

int c;
char str[100];
scanf("%s", str);
printf("|");
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
        printf("_");
    }

printf("|");
return 0;
```

}

main compiles. However When I try to use it and give it a word (of any length), it simply prints:
| 
_

and then the cursor moves right next to the underscore. What am I doing wrong? Why is the underscore printed after the "|" rather than next to it, as I didn't use \n ?

Comment: The  character that is read into `c` after the 
"word" is `'\n'`,

Comment: So basically I type in a word and by hitting enter, it reads /n? Is this because of scanf? How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685764/program-to-print-a-histogram-of-the-lengths-of-words-in-its-input/

Comment: @user3121023 I've done this. But now, it doesn't print the last " | " character. It again puts the cursor right next to the last underscored outputted. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you see is because the scanf("%s", str) line captures the word you input up to the default delimiter character which is space and then goes on to print '|' character then attempts to read more from stdin.

If you had entered say mylong word do you like it? then ctrl-z

You would see:

| _w_o_r_d_ _d_o_ _y_o_u_ _l_i_k_e_ _i_t_?_
_^Z
|

This is because the characters  word do you like it? are still in the stream to be processed.

If you only enter a single word without spaces then you will see what you observed.

The two lines:

```
char str[100];
scanf("%s", str);
```

could be removed and then you won't be capturing the word and doing nothing with it.

Alternatively, if you want to use scanf you could change like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[100];
    char* p = str;
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("|");
    while (*p != NULL) {
        putchar(*p++);
        printf("_");
    }
    printf("|");
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints each character in str, interspersing with the _ character.

Comment: Suggest avoid using `NULL` in a non-pointer context.  Maybe `while (*p)`

Comment: @chux just curious, why?

Comment: `*p != NULL` compares `*p` against a `NULL`.  `*p` is a `char`  `NULL` is the null pointer constant - maybe an integer with the value of 0, maybe not, maybe with the type `int`, maybe with the type `void*`, maybe not.  Its value may differ from 0 and provide incorrect functionality.   When comparing `char`, best to compare against an integer type like `'\0'` or simply `while (*p) {`.  Using  `while (*p != NULL) {` reflects poorly on the coder. `NULL` exists for pointer comparisons, not integer/`char` comparisons.

Comment: @chux I am thinking:  while (*p != '\0') more implies comparing with a character (ascii null).  Interesting point, thanks.

Comment: Detail: The C spec use describes _null_ (lowercase)  character as terminating a _string_ and `NULL` (uppercase) as the _null pointer constant_.  [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) uses the 3 letter _NUL_ to describe the code with the value of 0.

Comment: @angusComber does this happen only when scanf is scanning a string(char array) -- or all inputs, ie int, double, etc